# T-SQL Generate sequence of days after certain date

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a sequence of days as an array like the following:

```
DECLARE @days VARCHAR(MAX) = N'Monday, Wednesday, Friday'
```

And a *n* amount of occurrences like:

```
DECLARE @occurrences INT = 10
```

In this way I can generate a table using the following query and a custom table called **Numbers** which contains 1,000,000 numbers:

```
SELECT TOP @occurrences
    Item
FROM 
    dbo.SplitStrings_Numbers(@days, ',')
CROSS JOIN Numbers
ORDER BY n
```

The result is the following:

```
|----------------------|
| 1 | Monday           |
|----------------------|
| 2 | Wednesday        |
|----------------------|
| 3 | Friday           |
|----------------------|
| 4 | Monday           |
|----------------------|
| 5 | Wednesday        |
|----------------------|
| 6 | Friday           |
|----------------------|
```

Now what I need to complete this function is to start the sequence with the first day that occur based on a specified date.
So, when I declare start from 1st of September

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME = '2015-09-01'
```

The result should look like the following:

```
|------------------------------------|
| 1 | Wednesday      | 2015-09-02    |
|------------------------------------|
| 2 | Friday         | 2015-09-04    |
|------------------------------------|
| 3 | Monday         | 2015-09-07    |
|------------------------------------|
| 4 | Wednesday      | 2015-09-09    |
```

What I cannot calculate is this pseudo-code:
*"Given an array of days and a starting date, get the first occurrence after that date".*

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer but it will get you started:

```
;With DatesCte AS
(
SELECT TOP(@occurrences) DATEADD(DAY, number-1, @Start) As TheDate
FROM Numbers
), DatesWithWeekDay As
(
SELECT TheDate, DATENAME(WEEKDAY, TheDate) As WeekDayName
FROM DatesCTE
)
SELECT *
FROM DatesWithWeekDay
```